# Questions on Doctrine ORM Repository

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine, entitymanager

I'm quite new to Doctrine ORM, and I have some basic questions that I haven't been able to solve reading the documentation.

1. When I get a repository, such as

   > $repository = $entityManager->getRepository('Entity')

is that repository "updated" with Entity entities that I persisted after that line, or it's just a "snapshot"?

2. Related to the first point, this

   > $e = $repository->findOneBy($criteria);

will search "offline" in the repository itself (updated or not, as asked in the first point), or will cause a 'SELECT' query to my DB?

3. I have a bunch of objects and relations that need to be stored in a DB (avoinding duplicates). Would

   ```
   get Repository (only once)

   loop through all objects:

           search for object in the repository

                   if not found: persist object
                   if found: nothing
   flush (only once)
   ```

be a good practice?

Edit:

4. When I get a repository, is it "empty" by default  (until I start persisting stuff with the entity manager), or does it contain a SELECT * from the related table in the DB?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So many questions.  Don't know how to answer without writing a book.  A repository does not actually hold objects.  Think of it more as a database connection.  You might want to install the Symfony framework.  It has a very nice profile bar that shows all your queries and stuff like that.  There are several doctrine [chat channels](http://www.doctrine-project.org/community.html) available.  No idea how active they are.  And while the actual code may be a bit hard to read at first, some of your questions could be answered by looking at it.

Comment: @Cerad I tried to keep the questions as concise as posible, but you made me think I failed hehe

Comment: The questions are somewhat concise but the answers are not.  Especially since I am fairly certain you do not understand what a repository means in this context.  Plus the questions are not a good fit for stackoverflow.  However, [read the docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/#welcome-to-doctrine-2-orm-s-documentation), work through the examples and research the code.  Then come back and maybe ask again.